# Get value of MagicSuggest input

Tags: jquery, magicsuggest

I have an input with some value and I try to get the value of this. When I click on the 'valid' button it shows me 'undefined'. Here my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pv2we0x3/1/

```
$(function() {
  $('.suggest-tag').magicSuggest({
    data: [{
      "Id": 1,
      "Name": "hello"
    }, {
      "Id": 2,
      "Name": "world"
    }, {
      "Id": 3,
      "Name": "no"
    }],
    valueField: 'Id',
    displayField: 'Name',
  });

  $('.btn').click(function() {
    alert($('.suggest-tag').serialize());
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [documentation for MagicSuggest](http://nicolasbize.com/magicsuggest/doc.html), you need to call `getValue()` on the instance of the library you created in order to get the selected tag values:

```js
$(function() {
  var ms = $('.suggest-tag').magicSuggest({
    data: [{
      "Id": 1,
      "Name": "hello"
    }, {
      "Id": 2,
      "Name": "world"
    }, {
      "Id": 3,
      "Name": "no"
    }],
    valueField: 'Id',
    displayField: 'Name',
  });

  $('.btn').click(function() {
    console.log(ms.getValue());
  })
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magicsuggest/2.1.4/magicsuggest.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magicsuggest/2.1.4/magicsuggest.js"></script>

<form action="subscribe.php" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Tags</label>
    <div class="suggest-tag" value="[1,2,3]"></div>
  </div>
</form>

<input type="button" class="btn" value="Valid" />
```

Comment: i have updated my jsfiddle your code works if I have one input but my problem is i have many input
I have updated my jsfiddle

Comment: It seems there's no in-built method for working in this manner with this plugin. It seems exceptionally badly designed in that regard.